# Bridging header does not exist. Error occurs when converting from swift 3 to swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4.2, xcode10.1

I am trying to convert my app from swift 3 to swift 4.2 through Xcode version 10.1

However, I am encountering this error, as shown in the screenshot

[image: Error Screen]

What am I missing here? I researched other posts but still haven't found an answer.

What should I do to solve the problem? Am I supposed to generate the header file? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I had a ton of 'does not exist' or 'can't find' errors converting from swift 3 to 4. For me the answer was to remove the implicated file references from the project and then add the files in again. Clean, rebuild and repeat until everything compiles and links.

Comment: Hey @FryAnEgg, what would you mean by implicated file references from the project? Do you mean the dependencies in the podfile?

Comment: For your case, I would find the bridging header in the project tree view, ctrl-click and 'Show in Finder', then go back to file in project tree, press 'delete', select 'Remove Reference Only', then drag file from finder back into tree to add file back in.

Comment: Then clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

It seem path issue of your the "PetterUITests-Bridging-Header.h" file.
May you can try redefined the Bridging-Header file path.
Seek the Target -> Build setting -> SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER

[image]